# Base class has no destructor, but derived class does. Do I need to look for any pitfalls that DON'T relate to the heap?

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

In terms of inheritance, I understand that it's advised for your classes' destructors to be virtual, so the base class's destructor gets called correctly in addition to any derived destructors. However, I'm wondering if there are any stack-related issues that relate to derived objects in the following scenario.

Let's suppose we have a Base class that doesn't have a destructor (for whatever reason):

```
class Base{};
```

and a Derived class that DOES have a destructor:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  ~Derived(){}
};
```

And in the main...:

```
int main()
{
  Derived a;
  return 0;
}
```

Do I run into any issues from the Base class not having a destructor? My initial guess is that the compiler will just generate a default destructor for the Base class. Again, my question is mostly related to the stack rather than dynamic memory: is there any weirdo scenario I need to look out for in order to avoid a Derived destructor being called and the Base destructor is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base class has an implicit destructor. All will be fine.

A virtual base class destructor is used to allow a derived constructor to run when destructing via a pointer or reference to the base class. So in your case, this would be unsafe:

```
void destruct(Base &b) { b.~Base(); }
Derived d; destruct(d);
```

But this will be perfectly safe:

```
void destruct(Derived &d) { d.~Derived(); }
Derived d; destruct(d);
```

Comment: The function examples really help illustrate the point. Thanks much.

Comment: Neither of those examples are safe because `d` will be destructed twice

Comment: @M.M neither will compile, so both are safe.

Answer (score 2):

The rule you're thinking of is that if you delete an object of a derived type through a pointer to one of its base types and that base type does not have a virtual destructor the behavior is undefined. The code here doesn't delete anything, so the rule does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure safety, it is sufficient that every destructor (implicit or explicit) be at least one of:

- `virtual` (for base classes if you need to delete subclass instances through base class pointers)
- `protected` (to ensure that it is impossible to attempt to delete through a base class pointer)
- `final` (actually an attribute of the class, to avoid the entire possibility of subclasses).

There are a few rare edge cases where it is possible to safely call destructors, but they are generally a sign of bad design and are easy to avoid if you manage to happen across one of them.

As an aside, note that `std::shared_ptr` type-erases its deleter, so `std::shared_ptr<Base>` will work even if `Base` does not have a public destructor.

Comment: shared_ptr is such a pain in this regard.

Comment: @kakyo what exactly do you mean by that? Are you not using `make_shared` or something?

Comment: I'm using `shared_ptr`, and wish I could avoid invoking base-class destructor. But I haven't found a way.

Comment: `Class B : public Class A` and `protected: virtual A::~A() {}`, `public: B::~B() override {// cleanup}`, then `std::shared_ptr<ClassB> myvar = std::make_shared<ClassB>(); a_map.insert({id, myvar})`, finally when `a_map.erase(that_var)`. I found that `A::~A{}` is still called.

Comment: hmm, interesting, I reproduced it with MSVC2017.

Comment: Wait, your Class B didn't use virtual. I had a typo in my last comment.  `B::~B()` should be virtual.

Comment: `virtual` is implied when overriding an already-virtual method; I just tested adding it explicitly (and also virtual inheritance) and still cannot reproduce. Please edit the godbolt link until you can reproduce with at least one compiler.